# Why can't I access these JSON values?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-ajax

In one of my web pages I am making an AJAX call to retrieve a member's profile properties so that they can make changes.  The code being used to do this is as so:

```
        function loadProfileData() {
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "../handlers/getprofile.ashx",
                method: "POST"
            });

            request.done(function (msg) {
                if (msg.Success == false) {
                    $('#spnProfileErr').html(msg.Status);
                    $('#toastProfileFail').toast('show');
                }
                else {
                    $('#lastname').val(msg.MemberProfile.LastName); // textbox
                    $('#firstname').val(msg.MemberProfile.FirstName); // textbox
                    $('#bestemail').val(msg.MemberProfile.BestContactEmail); // textbox
                    $('#agerange').val(msg.MemberProfile.AgeRange);  // select control
                    $('#zipcode').val(msg.MemberProfile.ZIPCode); // textbox
                }  
            });

            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                $('#spnProfileErr').html('Unable to retrieve your existing profile at this time.');
                $('#toastProfileFail').toast('show');
            });
        }
```

The call to the web service works just fine, and it returns a JSON String, as follows:

[image: JSON returned by web service]

I can access the 'Success' and 'Status' properties of the returned JSON, but when I try to access the member profile properties of the MemberProfile in the JSON, it doesn't let me.  For example, accessing `msg.MemberProfile.LastName` throws an `undefined` error.

What am I not doing right?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: check the content-type header from your server, it should be a json type to trigger json parsing. if just manually parse it each time, it could fail when you upload it to public server configured with proper headers.

Comment: are you sure .status works? i see an "ok" string, not a number...

Comment: Success returns true or false indicating whether the web service found a matching profile record, while status returns a string of the error (or 'OK' if none).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you're receiving just a string, try use

```
var msg = JSON.parse(msg)
```

at beginning of your callback, so it will convert your string to a desired object, try out

Comment: That was it!  I was beginning to suspect I might need to cast the returned data to an object of some kind, but your fix worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: Great! but as @michael velentine's answer, you can add one more argument to your $.ajax call, dataType: "json", it will instruct your method return a parsed object, so you don't need parse it. happy coding

Comment: Thanks for that.  Noted and will use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the type:"json" property inside the ajax object, just after the method property

Comment: I think you mean `dataType: "json"`. `type:` is the old name for `method:`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).